# Scala: mock method in variable of class

Tags: scala, mockito

There is class:

```
case class A (client: Client) {

   def handle(s: String):String = s match {
        case sc if (sc.notEmpty) => ""
        case sc => s
   }

   val c = {
       val v = client.getValue()
       handle(v)
   }

}
```

The task is to test the result of c-variable, while mocking getValue()-invoke

```
 val client = mock[Client]
 (client.getValue) expects() returns("A")

 val a = A
 a.c should be "A"
```

I expected, test returns "A", but it return "".
Mocking getValue()-invoke does not works

Comment: You're not injecting `client` to `A` in any way I can see in the code, so whatever value it has it doesn't come from the mock. Also there is nothing in `A` that justifies it being a case class so you could just make it class and take `client` as constructor argument.

Comment: Yes, I missed this moment. I update my Answer

Comment: `return("a")` probably should be `returns("a")`

Comment: apply returns("a"), but with the same result